# Keep Deep Learning Model Loaded in Memory in Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, deep-learning, model

I have a deep learning model and I have added it in my django web REST API.
I want model to be always loaded in memory. Curretly when user request , model loads in memory and then released after some time. I want it to constantly loaded in ram so that the response time of my api got better. I have deployed API on Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load it from your `apps.py` file.

In your django app (Lets' call your app myapp), you may have a file called `apps.py` in the same level as your `models.py`, `views.py`, etc

You override the `ready()` method in there.

Example in `myapp/apps.py`

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

loaded_model = None

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        global loaded_model
        loaded_model = <load your model here>
```

Update in your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` settings in `settings.py` like this
`'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'`

You can then use this in your `views.py` like this

```py
from .apps import loaded_model

def my_view(request):
    result = loaded_model.<your_model_method>
```